# Stream extraction operator in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main() 
{
 int x=3;
 cout<<x++<<++x<<x++<<++x<<endl;
return 0; 
}
```

the output should be 3557 
but it is 6747. why???

Also:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main() 
{
 int x=3;
    cout <<x++<<endl;
    cout<<++x<< endl;
    cout<<x++<< endl;
    cout<<++x<< endl;
return 0; 
}
```

The above code gives:
3
5
5
7
(every digit in new line)
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: There have been many questions on this topic. The first example is undefined behavior.

Comment: So many duplicates to choose from...

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it was called undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int x=3;
 cout<<x++<<++x<<x++<<++x<<endl;
```

This is undefined behavior, so you could easily get **any** result.

```
int x=3;
cout <<x++<<endl; // x = 3, post incremented to 4...
cout<<++x<< endl; // here x = 4 and preincremented to x = 5
cout<<x++<< endl; // x = 5 , postincremented to 6...
cout<<++x<< endl; // so here x = 6 but preincremented to 7
```

[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

[unexpected output in cout and printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10925530/1141471)

Comment: You should add a link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/2700399) for an explanation of the undefined behavior.